# Correct syntax for php inside a feed request

Tags: php, xml, youtube-api

I have a very basic query string which passes a ID to a receiving page.

On that page, I need to dynamically call the YouTube API, giving my playlistID.

I'm having to use PHP for this, and it's a little out of my comfort zone, so hopefully someone can wade in with a quick fix for me.

Here is my variable

```
$playlist;
```

And I need to replace the 77DC230FBBCE4D58 below with that variable.

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/77DC230FBBCE4D58?v=2';
```

Any help, as always, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the `$playlist` variable is set you can construct the feed URL as :

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/' . $playlist . '?v=2';
```

or

```
$feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/$playlist?v=2";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/'.rawurlencode($playlist).'?v=2';
```

Or perhaps a little neater:

```
$feedurl = sprintf(
    'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/%s?v=2',
    rawurlencode($playlist)
);
```

(Note: [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode) is used just in case [not that it's likely with YouTube playlist IDs] the `$playlist` value contains any funky characters.)

More infos:

- [String concatenation](http://php.net/language.operators.string) with the `.` operator
- Encoding potentially "unsafe" URL characters with [rawurlencode](http://php.net/rawurlencode)
- Adding values to "formatted strings" with [sprintf](http://php.net/sprintf)

Comment: great, thanks. Will give that try in addition to the tips above

Answer (score 0):

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/' . $playlist . '?v=2';
```

you use a full stop to join strings in PHP

Comment: thanks for the answer, was just what I needed. Now to go read a bit deeper on php!